# Qt QML specify ListView delegate property from outside

Tags: qt, qml

I have a ChoicePage.qml like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

Item {
    property alias searchBar: searchBar
    property alias model: listView.model
    property alias itemDelegate: listView.delegate

    ColumnLayout {
        height: parent.height
        width: parent.width * 0.9
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter

        TextField {
            id: searchBar
            Layout.preferredHeight: parent.height * 0.1
            Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width
            placeholderText: qsTr("Search..")
        }

        ListView {
            id: listView
            Layout.fillHeight: true
            Layout.preferredWidth: parent.width
            ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {}
            clip: true
            spacing: height * 0.01
        }
    }
}
```

And a TestChoicePage.qml like this:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

ChoicePage {
    model: proxy.list // c++ proxy that expose a list of QObject*
    itemDelegate: RadioButton {
        height: ListView.view.height * 0.1
        width: ListView.view.width
        text: modelData.description
    }
}
```

I would like to have the RadioButton delegate item inside ChoicePage and define the modelData.description or whatelse the page needs from TestChoicePage, Test2ChoicePage and so on.
Is it possible?

Comment: It should be possible, are you seeing a problem or error?

Comment: No, but I don't know how to do it. The only way I see is to specify the RadioButton delegate in every page that implements ChoicePage. I would like to keep the RadioButton defined for all pages inside the ChoicePage and specify his text from outside but I'm not able. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Model's data cannot be accessed outside the delegate. Any model related bindings have to defined within the delegate.

Non model related properties of the delegate can be controlled externally.
New properties can be defined outside the delegate. These new properties can be binded to the delegate's properties.

See example below:

```
List.qml:
ListView {
    width: 200
    height: 200
    spacing: 5
    property string rectColor: ""
    delegate: Rectangle{
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height / 5
        color: rectColor
        required property string modelProperty
        RadioButton{
            text: parent.modelProperty
        }
    }
}  

main.qml:
MyList{
    model: myCppList
    rectColor: "green"
}
```